# Change Page Control With Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a simple page control set up with two different pages.  I have a button called nextButton, and if the user hits that button, I want to change the page and scroll to the next page.

My page control works, and I can scroll to change pages, but the button does not work at all.  It is getting called though.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * TUTORIALNUMBEROFPAGES, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = TUTORIALNUMBEROFPAGES;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;

    CGRect pageFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
    pageFrame.origin.x = pageFrame.size.width * 0;
    pageFrame.origin.y = 0;

    self.pageOne.frame = pageFrame;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.pageOne];

    pageFrame.origin.x = pageFrame.size.width * 1;
    self.pageTwo.frame = pageFrame;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.pageTwo];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender 
{    
    if (pageControlUsed) {
        return;
    }

    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{    
    pageControlUsed = NO;
}

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender 
{        
    NSInteger currentPage = self.pageControl.currentPage;
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(currentPage * self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
    pageControlUsed = YES;
}

- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender
{
    [self changePage:self];
}
```

Comment: What about making your change page method take an integer argument?

Comment: That method is tied to the page control, I want to still be able to click the page control buttons and make it change pages.

Comment: Then make a new method that takes an int.  one specific to that button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 - (IBAction)nextPage:(id)sender 
  {        
     NSInteger currentPage = self.pageControl.currentPage + 1;
     CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(currentPage * self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
    pageControlUsed = YES;
 }

  - (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender
  {
      [self nextPage:self];

  }
```

Notice the +1 in that code.  Before, you were literally setting the content offset exactley equal to the original offset because you were just taking the value of the page control.

Comment: This works, however I current have two pages, and this takes me past the second page.  How would I get this to stop at the last page without going over to another blank page?

Comment: Never mind, I was putting my if statement in the wrong method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender 
{        
    NSInteger currentPage = self.pageControl.currentPage;
    if([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]){
       currentPage+=1;
    }
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(currentPage * self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
    pageControlUsed = YES;
}

- (IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender
{
    [self changePage:sender];//if this action is attached just to your button
}
```